# solution of the set of real non-linear equations

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, systems-of-equations

I have a set of real non-linear equations as following:

\begin{equation}
y_0 = f(y_0,y_1) \\
y_1 = g(y_0,y_1,y_2) \\
y_2 = g(y_1,y_2,y_3) \\
\vdots \\
y_{n-1} = g(y_{n-2},y_{n-1},y_n) \\
y_n = f(y_{n-1},y_n) \\
\end{equation}

In other words, there are limited number of variables each a function of itself, previous variable, and next variable. Using an iterative computer simulation the solution of this system is found and the convergence is achieved. Is there any analytic method to find the solution?

$$
g(y_0,y_1,y_2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{e^{-(y_0 + y_1)^2/8} - e^{-(y_1 + y_2)^2/8}}{Q(\frac{y_0 + y_1}2) - Q(\frac{y_1 + y_2}2)}
$$
and
$$
f(y_0,y_1) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{e^{-(y_0 + y_1)^2/8}}{1 - Q(\frac{y_0 + y_1}2)}
$$
where $Q(.)$ is the [Q-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function).

Comment: Can you give a flavor of the first equations ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank for your response. I edited the questions.

Comment: This is a very interesting problem indeed. May I ask what kind of algorithm you use ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks for your attention. I simply start with a random vector $\mathbf{y}_0$ and do the iterations in a periodic top-bottom manner.

Comment: What kind of convergence do you observe ? Do you have any conditions for the $y$'s ? I like this problem !